# setting an array element with a sequence error whilst trying to plot

Tags: python, numpy

```
img = mpimg.imread('file.tif') #imports image

im_x = np.sum(img, axis=0) #sum the rows of the array

hist = pl.hist(im_x) #returns a list - this works fine

test = np.array(hist) #turns hist into a numpy array so i can plot it

plt.plot(test)
plt.show()
```

I'm trying to import an image to an array, sum the values of each row, then plot this in a histogram.

The code above gives me the 'setting an array element with a sequence error' message, which I don't understand as it's a numpy array.

I've only been using python for a week, so it could be something really obvious I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In the words of Henry David Thoreau, simplify, simplify:

```
img = mpimg.imread('file.tif') #imports image    
im_x = np.sum(img, axis=0) #sum the rows of the array
plt.hist(im_x)
plt.show()
```